# My local git folders are full of files. Why are they empty on github?

Tags: git, github

My local folders from my git repository are full of python files. Why are they empty on github and how can I fix this?

[Repo](https://github.com/2pt0/mother)

mother_devices and mother_main should be full of files, as they are on my local machine. git status reads:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Ubuntu 15.04 with latest github. Any advice would be wonderful.

Comment: Hm, interesting.  Try running `git check-ignore *` in one of those directories.

Comment: Or, to check all of the cases, have you remembered to `git push`?

Comment: check ignore has come up empty handed.

Comment: I am simply going to move all the files to another folder, remove all signs git ever existed there and overwrite.

Comment: No, wait, stop - that's not what you want to do.

Comment: First, let's back up a second.  Is this a brand new repository that you've created on GitHub but didn't initialize it with anything?

Comment: I foolishly removed my old github repo in order to rearrange. Then init-ed the new local repo after de-gitting the old one. Pushed new local to new remote, stopped working. I think I know the issue but I'll test it tomorrow. I'm up far too late for this. I'll be back once I've fixed it

Comment: Woudl a `git add -A .` work better than `git add *`?

Comment: Honestly I don't know _why_ it worked but doing the above fixed it. I know what not to do in the future :P